# Can't run web application from localhost

Tags: localhost

I have a problem when I run the web application project.

It gives me the following error:

[alt text http://www6.0zz0.com/2009/04/19/19/934715868.jpg](http://www6.0zz0.com/2009/04/19/19/934715868.jpg)

The error occurs with Web Application Projects and Web Site Projects.

I tried the following URL, but it gives me the same error: `http://localhost:3306/mobileApplication`

This to enter the database:

```
http://localhost:3306/TheLostNumberApplication/
http://localhost:3306/TheLostNumberApplication/faces/welcomeJSF.jsp
```

It looks like the localhost doesn't run and I use MySQL and I don't know where can I find the localhost to run it.

What could be the matter?

#### Update:

I tried several solutions, but it still has the same problem (localhost doesn't run) ...

I want to ask now I have an Apache service. Should I have the Apache Tomcat, not the Apache service? Or doesn't it matter?

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information. What are you trying to run? Are you executing through Visual Studio? Some other ide?

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't use BBCode—please use the editing tools from within the posting form to format your question.

Comment: Edit your question properly. Ask a more precise question. Keep it programming related. close++;

Comment: I use netbeans to run a web application (jsb) >> we retreive some information from database and the localhost appears that it doesn't work ..

Comment: The image is not appearing ..

Answer (score 3):

MySQL, which by default runs on port 3306, does not provide a web front-end. You will need to find out what port is opened by the webserver you're running. Typically, they run on port 80, port 8080, or port 8000.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a firewall that could be blocking this?

Answer (score 0):

What are you using as your Java Application Server? You need to start it first.

You'll find it under Administrative Tools -> Services in Windows.

Comment: i do this step and it still doesn't work >_<

Answer (score 0):

Go into Internet Explorer Tools, click on the advanced tab, and in the settings tree, under the browsing branch, make sure that the setting "Show friendly HTTP error messages" is turned off.

This itself, won't solve your problem, but often Internet Explorer hides the truth from you when your web application is not executing properly.  When you refresh, it will tell you what *really* went wrong (it might be a 404) but at least Internet Explorer won't be making assumptions about why the page failed.

I have had this myself, Internet Explorer reporting a 404 error, when in actuality, it was a syntaxical problem which was reported when this option was off.  Turn it off and either update your question accordingly, or fix the problem.  If this doesn't work, refer back to the other answers here.

Answer (score 0):

if you're on a newer Windows then check your hosts file - microsoft removed the localhost entry in Vista(?). This can make life confusing when your dns refuses to resolve it.

check %windir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts